# “Font shape undefined” with LaTeX - twentysecondcv.cls

Tags: fonts, xelatex

I am doing my CV with twentysecondcv.cls with Texlive2016 but I have a problem with the font shape. It shows a default font which is not so clear and doesn't recognize enter code here ClearSan.sty which is declared in the .cls file as a provide package. I really don't know how to make XeLatex to run it. I found many pages about font shape undefined but I haven't found a solution. Please if someone knows how to fix that I will appreciate a lot. For me is not important necessarily to use ClearSans any sanserif should be better than my output file.

Thanks in advance

Here the file

[allfiles](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByqezhSm2i9ZZnpUYzNTSmh2Q1k)

In the console appears this

> Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

The twentysecondcv.cls outputfile from the author has the fontshape I would like for my cv sanserif

```
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `twentysecondcv',
               but the document class provides `ClearSans'.

Document Class: ClearSans 
(./ClearSans.sty



LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 13.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 56.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/FontAwesome(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/FontAwesome(0)/m/n' instead on input line 56.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/ClearSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 72.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Answer (score 6):

Your font package was written wrong `\usepackage{fontspec}` you should call the package as `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` , try this it should change the font of the document to sanserif. Moreover, you can also delete the setmainfont if not needed.

```
\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

An here is the implementation

```
\documentclass[]{twentysecondcv}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\setmainfont[
   Path = /Library/Fonts/,
  UprightFont = ClearSans-Regular ,
  BoldFont = ClearSans-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = ClearSans-Italic ,
  Extension = .ttf
]{ClearSans.ttf}
\hyphenation{Geoscience behaviour surface des-truc-tor}
```

I have compiled the file for you , here you can download the full tex cv, just change the profile picture, unzip the document and your good to go [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dv3gt3mq35agy24/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex-master.zip?dl=0).